# Windows のコマンドプロンプトで、画面出力した上で、ログにも出力したい

Tags: windows, コマンドプロンプト

**Windows のコマンドプロンプトで、画面出力した上で、テキスト形式でログ出力したいのですが、どうすれば良いでしょうか？**

---

**例えば、chkdsk**
・時間がかかる上に、進行状況に応じてメッセージが追加されていきます
・ログは最後にまとめて出力すれば良いのですが、途中で、誤ってコマンドプロンプトを閉じた時、ログを確認する方法はあるでしょうか？
・コマンドプロンプトを一旦閉じてしまったら、処理の履歴を確認することは出来ない？

---

**今、下記を試しているのですが、どういう意味ですか？**
・画面には何も表示されていないのですが、処理が全部終了してから「出力する」という意味でしょうか？
・進行状況に応じてメッセージが追加されていったりはしない？？

> コマンド > ファイル名

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windowsに標準搭載されているPowerShellをつかって、コマンドプロンプトから以下を実行すればいいと思います。

```
powershell -Command "<コマンド> 2>&1 | Add-Content -Path <ファイル名> -PassThru"
```

なお、

> 今、下記を試しているのですが、どういう意味ですか？

についてですが、`>`は、コマンドの標準出力(i.e. エラー以外の画面出力)をファイルに書きこむ、リダイレクトと呼ばれるものです。これをした場合、画面には出力されません。ファイルには進行状況に応じて出力が追加されます。

私の上記コマンドの`2>&1`はコマンドの標準出力にエラー出力をまとめるものです。それをさらに`|`(パイプ)によってPowerShellコマンドレットのAdd-Contentに渡して処理させています。

Comment: 「ファイルには進行状況に応じて出力が追加されます」。自分が予想していた階層と違うところに出力されていたので、最初気が付きませんでした。「Windowsに標準搭載されているPowerShell」。初めて知りました。大変参考になりました

Answer (score 2):

別解。
Windows 10 Anniversary Update だと Windows Subsystem for Linux と言う機能が使えます。
それ以外の Windows でも cygwin / mingw をインストールしてあれば同じように
Unix コマンドの `tee` が使えます。

```
C> examplecommand | tee logfile.txt
```

とすると `examplecommand` の標準出力が `logfile.txt` とコンソールの両方に同時に出力されます。

リダイレクトの話は既に出ているので解説略。

> 途中で、誤ってコマンドプロンプトを閉じた時、ログを確認する方法はあるでしょうか？
>   ・コマンドプロンプトを一旦閉じてしまったら、処理の履歴を確認することは出来ない？

標準の `cmd.exe` というかコマンドプロンプトウィンドウには
 [閉じた後も] ログを永続化して保存する機能はなさそうです。

`chkdsk` のログを `tee` で保存してみたら途中経過のパーセント表示も保存されてしまい
ちょっとかっこ悪いログになっちゃいました。

Comment: 「Windows Subsystem for Linux」、初めて知りました。Ubuntuをダウンロードする必要があるみたいなので、今回は試さなかったのですが、単純に凄いなと思いました。「Unix コマンドの tee」。初めて知りました。参考になりました。ちなみに、当初、普通のリダイレクトで試していたのですが、途中経過のパーセント表示も全部保存されたため、思ったよりも手間でした(正規表現で置換したのですが、処理に時間がかかりました)

Comment: 「Windows Subsystem for Linux」はUbuntu用のバイナリをWindowsで実行できるようにする機能で、Ubuntuそのもののダウンロードは不要です。標準では無効になっているので前準備が必要なはずですが。

Comment: 「Ubuntuをダウンロードする必要がある」と勘違いしていました。コメントありがとうござしました。